# Isolating an alphanumerical ID that can be anywhere in a text based cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I'm trying to isolate a certain character string from a text cell.

For example, I would like to extract `"AB-T120-15"` from the string `"His server ID was AB-T120-15 and his problem was that he needed a reboot"`

`AB-T120-15` is an example, but they would all be codes of a max length of 13 characters starting by something like `AB-T`, `CL-R`, etc.

The codes can appear anywhere in a text field of the column.

`string_split()` cannot be used since the DB we are under is older.

I have tried many combinations of Substring and LEFT, but I cannot seem to have it worked.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done, thanks. Not super familiar with the etiquette of Stackoverflow yet and am not even programmer by trade hehe

Answer (score 1):

String operations are not the strength of SQL Server -- which I assume you are using.

You can do this with rather painful string manipulation:

```
select left(stuff(str, 1, patindex('%[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z]%', str) - 1, ''),
            charindex(' ', stuff(str, 1, patindex('%[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z]%', str), '') + ' ')
           )
from (values ('His server ID was AB-T120-15 and his problem was that he needed a reboot')) v(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I understand what you do here, where you look for a pattern. Which makes sense. I am trying to apply that selection to an entire column of values.

For example:

`code`
select t.ticket_subject

from dm_all_tickets as t where (t.ticket_subject contains content with the pattern)